# azure queue service calls perfomance

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-cloud-services, azure-queues

I am newbie with `Aure Queue service`. According the [examples](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started) which I've seen, there are 2 methods to retrieve messages, `getMessage` and `getMessages`. The worker role has a while loop which try to retrieve 1 or more messages per cycle. If there are no messages, it sleeps for a moment. For queues which do not contain a lot of messages it is not a good solution, because you have to pay for a lot of queue calls which returns a null value. Is it a way to use  `Aure Queue service` as a producer-consumer, which the worker role would be awaken by a trigger after the queue received a message?, or is it a way to define an event in the worker role which the queue could invoke after receiving a new message?
May be using `Azure functions`?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure WebJobs SDK does offer such a pattern (trigger a function run on new message) -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk, however it's still implemented as a while loop, it's just more elegant to work with.

In essence, there is no **push** mechanism for Azure Storage Queues. Everything is a **pull**, SDK or no SDK. Just grab a *bucket* of messages for every run. 32 messages instead of one. Be *chunky*, not *chatty*.

Referencing my answer to a similar question for the really great Azure Storage Queues videos by Mark Simms that it links to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036911/4148708