# Does .NET Core support creating webjobs that get started by an Azure QueueTrigger?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I have an existing webjob (.NET 4.6.1) that runs fine and gets triggered whenever a message arrives in a queue. I'm investigating how to migrate some applications to .NET Core 1.0 and as part of that I did some research.

It looks like at this point in time, .NET Core 1.0 only supports webjobs that run on a schedule and have no special Webjob features, such as this example: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/08/azure-webjobs-with-dotnet-core-rc2/

To have a queue message trigger the job I need the features of the Webjob packages. When I add any of the WebJobs Nuget packages (including beta versions), I get the error:

```
Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core 2.0.0-beta2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core 2.0.0-beta2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

I did apply a workaround for the Azure Storage already as described in:
https://jeremiedevillard.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/use-the-azure-storage-library-in-netcore-application/
but thas apparently does not solve the issue for the Webjob package.

I am aware of some workaround of deploying a non-.NET Core webjob next to a .NET Core website as described here: [How do I deploy an Azure WebJob alongside a .NET Core Web App via Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919723/how-do-i-deploy-an-azure-webjob-alongside-a-net-core-web-app-via-git)
 but - although that would work - I just want to know if I can port my webjob to .NET Core 1.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

TIA,
Jeroen

Comment: so you have your answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no **push/notify** mechanism built in Azure Storage Queues, it's still polling.

You could just poll the queue every X seconds and check for new messages. That's what the SDK is doing anyway, but in a civilized, elegant way. Nothing wrong with doing that.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

> #### Azure Storage Queues
>
> Push-style API: No
>
> ---
>
> #### Service Bus Queues
>
> Push-style API: **Yes**
>   **[OnMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_OnMessage_System_Action_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__)** and OnMessage sessions .NET API.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I may look into the sourcecode of the SDK to find a clue on how to do it.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the mechanics of Azure Storage Queues, these videos make for a very good primer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036911/4148708

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Azure WebJobs that use of WebJobs SDK in .NET Core is not supported currently.  The following is the snipped from the [davidebbo](https://github.com/davidebbo) mentioned. More details info please refer to the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/745).

> To clarify, Azure WebJobs that use .NET Core work fine. It's specifically the use of the WebJobs SDK that is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we'll just have to wait for it then, when they will work on .Net Core support after the release of Webjob SDK version 2.0.